# Semaphore - why my threads are running one after the other and not in concurrent?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I'm trying to write a program that in the `Main` class one can initiate unknown amount of new threads.
Each thread in turn should call to a *Singleton* `Copier` class which should call a file transfer action.

My goal is, regardless the amount of threads requests, is to **limit** the number of concurrent transfers to 2 transfers, so I thought solving it with `Semaphore`.
My problem is, it's seems the threads are running one after the other and not in concurrent.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
public class Copier {

    private static final int POOL_SIZE = 2;
    private static volatile Copier instance = null;
    private static Semaphore semaphore;

    private Copier() {

    }

    public static Copier getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (Copier.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Copier();
                    semaphore = new Semaphore(POOL_SIZE);
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void fileTransfer(CopyThread copyThread) {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            System.out.println("Running thread...");
            copyThread.run();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            semaphore.release();
            System.out.println("Thread released..");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `Main` class:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Copier copier = Copier.getInstance();
        CopyThread copyThread1 = new CopyThread();
        CopyThread copyThread2 = new CopyThread();

        copier.fileTransfer(copyThread1);
        copier.fileTransfer(copyThread2);
    }
}
```

When running it - you can see by the output the threads running one after the other, while my purpose is to have up to 2 concurrent threads.
What did I do wrong?

```
Running thread...
3.998784MB were transferred in 5.902514932 seconds
Thread released..
Running thread...
4.062673MB were transferred in 7.199550077 seconds
Thread released..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to call `start()` instead of `run()` otherwise it won't start your threads such that the transfer will be done sequentially which is actually the root cause of your current issue.

Anyway, for me your code should be rewritten as the class `Copier` should not even **start()** the threads as it is not its duty.

#### 1. Rewrite the method `fileTransfer()`

```
public void fileTransfer() {
    try {
        semaphore.acquire();
        System.out.println("Running transfer...");
        // Code that performs the transfer
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        semaphore.release();
        System.out.println("Thread released..");
    }
}
```

#### 2. Implement the method `run()` of `CopyThread` properly

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // Here I call fileTransfer() on Copier instead of the other way around
    Copier.getInstance().fileTransfer();
}
```

#### 3. Make `semaphore` non static and final

```
private final Semaphore semaphore;

private Copier() {
    this.semaphore = new Semaphore(POOL_SIZE);
}
```

#### 4. Use an inner class to lazy create your instance

```
public class Copier {
    ...
    public static Copier getInstance() {
        return Holder.instance;
    }
    ...
    private static class Holder {
        private static final Copier instance = new Copier();
    }
}
```

#### 5. Rewrite your `main` method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CopyThread copyThread1 = new CopyThread();
    CopyThread copyThread2 = new CopyThread();

    copyThread1.start();
    copyThread2.start();
}
```

**Output:**

```
Running transfer...
Running transfer...
Thread released..
Thread released..
```

Comment: nice post, but I would reword the first paragraph such that it elicit what the OP did wrong clearly.

Comment: @UmNyobe you are right, I rewrote it a little bit, thanks

Comment: @NicolasFilotto - thanks for the great marks & modifications :)
Just one small question - what are the advantages of creating my singleton instance with _inner class_ like you suggested, rather the way I did?

Comment: because 1. It is easier to read, 2. it is less error prone and 3. unlike double-check locking idiom with volatile, it works whatever the target JDK while double-check locking idiom with volatile only works starting from JDK 5.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `Thread.run()` you do not start the thread, you just execute the method sequentially. You need to call `start()`. (I am assuming `CopyThread` is a `Thread`).

Java Puzzlers by Joshua Bloch has a chapter with a very similar example.